# Create sub lists from list of strings based on string starts with

Tags: c#, string, linq

Fist time posting, so forgive me on formatting...
I have a text file that I've read in using File.ReadLines() and stored sequentially to a List.
I then want to find the first instance of a string that starts with "Student".  Then I want to get all of the strings in the list up to the next instance of a string that starts with "Student" and stop just before it.  Copy those strings to a sub list, and then rinse and repeat until the end of the file is reached.

**Example of text file:**

> something on line 1
>
> something on line 2
>
> **Student**...: Joe Smith
>
> Id...: 12345
>
> Major...: Math
>
> unknown number of more lines
>
> **Student**...: Jane Smith
>
> Id...: 54321
>
> Major...: Nursing
>
> more lines
>
> **Student**...: John Doe
>
> Id...: 11223
>
> Major: Anatomy
>
> even more lines.

I'd like the list of lines per student to look like this:

Student 1

> Student...: Joe Smith
>
> Id...: 12345
>
> Major...: Math
>
> unknown number of more lines

Student 2

> Student...: Jane Smith
>
> Id...: 54321
>
> Major...: Nursing
>
> more lines

I've used a foreach to iterate the lines.  Each line is added to a new list.  When I find a string that starts with "Student" then I create a new student object and store those lines in the sub list to it.  Then I clear the sublist and then continue on with the foreach, creating new student objects.

Current issues
I miss the last student.  I know I could have the if statement that checks if the current line starts with "Student" to include checking if the current line is the last line in the list, but I feel there has to be a better/fast way to do this.
I have to add the && lines.Count > 3 because there are a few lines before the first instance of "Student" which I want to skip.

Linq examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(args[0]).ToList();  
List<string> student_lines = new List<string>();
foreach(string line in lines) 
{ 
    if(line.StartsWith("Student...", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && lines.Count > 3) 
    {
        students.Add(new Student(student_lines)); 
        student_lines.Clear(); 
    } 
    lines.Add(line)
}
```

Comment: easier to `File.ReadAllText`, split on "Student", and split the parts by `\r\n`

Comment: can you elaborate on split on "Student"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var results =
    lines
        .Aggregate(new[] { new List<string>() }.ToList(), (a, x) =>
        {
            if (x.StartsWith("Student"))
            {
                a.Add(new List<string>());
            }
            a.Last().Add(x);
            return a;
        })
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(x => new Student(x))
        .ToList();
```

From your sample data I get this:

[image: result]

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.  I've been out of the loop with C# for some time so I'll take a look at what all is going on here.  Thanks for the input!

Comment: Fantastic work!  This is exactly what I wanted.  Works great!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
if (args.Length < 1) return;                // optional check if any args

string text = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);

string[] parts = text.Split(new[] { "Student" }, 0);

string[][] lines = Array.ConvertAll(parts, part => part.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, 1));

Debug.Print(lines[1][1]);        // "Id...: 12345"
```

Answer (score -1):

It is really vague what you are trying to do but here is a very basic example of what I think you are doing.

Now the only thing you need to do is change the `fileName` param.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line = null;
    Student student = null;
    IList<Student> students = new List<Student>();
    using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
    {
        while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                continue; //continue execution on extra lines
            if(line.StartsWith("Student...", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                student = new Student();
                students.Add(student);
            }

            if (student != null)
                student.Lines.Add(line);


        }

        fileReader.Close();
    }
}

class Student
{
    public IList<string> Lines { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

In a nutshell all this little program does is starts reading a file line by line (note `while ((line = fileReader.ReadLine()) != null)` will set the value of `line` to the next line in the file or `null` when the file has been completely read.

Next it checks for empty lines (we dont care about empty lines so we move on)

We then check if the `line` startsith `Student...` now we are using `StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` so we can compare case insensitive.

If this is a Student line, we then create a new student and `Add()` it to our `students` collection.

Finally as long as `student` is not null we can add the contents of `line` to the student `.Lines` property.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote.  Thanks for the info.  I started with this method but decided the input text file isn't that large (maybe 100k lines) and the ReadLines() function is what I'd like to use.